# Azure devOps multi stage pipeline release status response

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I am running a multi stage pipeline and need to run a production build pipeline after the success of pre production release pipeline so is there any way around to check the status of the release pipeline using RestAPI in azure Devops and get this response in build pipeline.

To trigger the production stage of build pipeline based on the results of the pre production release pipeline

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use REST API for this, you can use the result of your pipeline as a trigger for your second pipeline:

[Configure pipeline resource triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#configure-pipeline-resource-triggers)